# How to find c1 in Big Theta?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

In the case that we have polynomial:

```
f(n) = 8n^2 - 4n + 2
```

We will then have g(n) = n^2

```
BigTheta(f(n)) = 0 <= c1g(n) <= f(n) <= c2g(n), n > n0
```

I know that to find c2, we would add all coefficients:
8  -  4  +  2
And therefore c2 = 2, correct?
But what about c1?
Will c1 ALWAYS be equal to 1? Or will it always be equal to the smallest positive coefficient?
What is the general rule here?

Another example, if we have:

```
f(n) = 9n^2 + 3n/2 + 1/4
g(n) =  n^2
```

I know that c2 = 10.75
But will c1 = 1 or 1/4?

I'm looking for a general rule to figure out c1 giving me a tight bound.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what it will "always" be. But for your example, 8n^2 - 4n + 2 is always at least as big as 4n^2, so you could choose c1 to be 4 (or anything smaller: 1, 2, or 3). How did I get that? Well, we want a function of the form c1n^2 that is smaller than f(n); 8n^2 is smaller than 8n^2 + 2 (in other words, we can ignore terms that are added), but we have to worry about the -4n term. So, the simplest approach is to say that since 4n is smaller than 4n^2, 8n^2 - 4n^2 will always be smaller than 8n^2 - 4n + 2 (because I am subtracting something bigger). Therefore,

4n^2 = 8n^2 - 4n^2 <= 8n^2 - 4n <= 8n^2 - 4n + 2 <= f(n)

so you can choose c1 equal to 4.

There isn't a single correct answer in these problems. You just need a constant that you can show makes c1n^2 smaller than f(n).

For the second example, you are adding all the terms, so just drop them. 9n^2 <= 9n^2 + 3n/2 + 1/4, so choose c_1 = 9.

I suppose as a general algorithm, you could take the largest order coefficient and subtract all the negative coefficients (and ignore the positive ones). That will give you a correct answer, assuming that you get a positive value. If not, you'll either have to fiddle with n0 or make c1 a fraction smaller than one.